# Rotating a canvas display depending on where the user clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a `html5 canvas` display that i would like to rotate once a user clicks. I am trying to figure out the best way to allow the animation take effect. I would like the rotation to be smooth and no matter where the user clicks the selected panel would rotate to the top.

I am not sure of the best way to go about this since this is my very first canvas project, and I figured i would open the floor to all of you.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JRgtg/

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your task is fairly complex:

- create an object for each arc segment around the circle
- save the arc objects in an arcs[] array
- create a function that draws a specified arc at a specified angle
- (the arc is drawn as a path)
- listen for mousedown events
- in the mousedown handler, use context.isPointInPath to see if user clicked on an arc-segment-path
- if clicked, rotate the clicked arc to the top of the circle using animation

Illustration of arc positions before and after the gold arc was clicked.

The gold arc rotated to the top:

[image][image]

Commented Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/ZUtL8/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    // canvas and context reference variables
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var $canvas=$("#canvas");
    var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    // save PI to variables since they are used often
    var PI=Math.PI;
    var PI2=Math.PI*2;

    // animation variables
    var rotation;
    var desiredRotation;
    var deltaRotation=PI/120;  // rotate at about 360 degrees over 2 seconds

    // define a color for each segment
    var colors=["red","green","blue","gold","purple"];
    var topAngle=clampAngle(PI*3/2-(PI2/colors.length)/2);
    var gapAngle=2*PI/180; // 3 degree gap between arcs

    // hold the arc objects in an arcs[] array
    var arcs=createArcs(150,150,50,75,colors);

    // draw the arcs 
    for(var i=0;i<arcs.length;i++){
        drawArc(arcs[i],true);
    }

    // listen for mouse events
    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});

    // utility function
    // make sure angles are expressed between 0 & 2*PI
    function clampAngle(a){
        return((a+PI2*2)%PI2);
    }

    // create arc objects for each color
    function createArcs(cx,cy,insideRadius,outsideRadius,colors){
        var arcs=[];
        for(var i=0;i<colors.length;i++){
            var a1=clampAngle(i*PI2/colors.length+topAngle);
            var a2=clampAngle(a1+PI2/colors.length-gapAngle);
            arcs.push({
                segment:i,
                x:cy, 
                y:cy, 
                r1:insideRadius, 
                r2:outsideRadius,
                a1:a1,
                a2:a2,
                color:colors[i],
                rotation:0
            });
        }
        return(arcs);
    }

    // draw one arc
    function drawArc(arc,draw){
        var x = arc.x + arc.r1 * Math.cos(arc.a2);
        var y = arc.y + arc.r1 * Math.sin(arc.a2);
        // define
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(arc.x,arc.y,arc.r2,arc.a1,arc.a2);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.arc(arc.x,arc.y,arc.r1,arc.a2,arc.a1,true);
        ctx.closePath();
        // 
        if(draw){
            ctx.fillStyle=arc.color;
            ctx.fill();
        }
    }

    // handle mouse events
    function handleMouseDown(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // hit test each arc 
      var hit=-1;
      for(var i=0;i<arcs.length;i++){
          // define the target arc
          drawArc(arcs[i]);
          if(ctx.isPointInPath(mouseX,mouseY)){
              hit=i;
          }
      }
      // if use clicked on arc, rotate it to the top
      if(hit>=0){
          rotation=0;
          desiredRotation=clampAngle(topAngle-arcs[hit].a1);
          animate();
      }
    }

    // animate the rotation of the clicked arc
    function animate(){

        // stop animating if the arc has been rotated to the top
        if(rotation<=desiredRotation){ requestAnimationFrame(animate); }

        if(rotation>desiredRotation){ rotation=desiredRotation; }

        // clear the canvas
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

        // add a rotation increment to each arc
        for(var i=0;i<arcs.length;i++){
            var arc=arcs[i];
            arc.a1=clampAngle(arc.a1+deltaRotation);
            arc.a2=clampAngle(arc.a2+deltaRotation);
            drawArc(arc,true);
        }

        // increase the rotation angle by the rotation increment
        rotation=clampAngle(rotation+deltaRotation);
    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Click on a color-arc and it will rotate to top.</h4>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, I was completely off path on this one. I guess I will be rethinking my code a bit for this. One question that i do have is where are you setting the inside and outside radii like previously?

Comment: The inside/outside radii are defined as r1,r2 in the arc object ;)